# How to trace count of events in two groups over time?

Tags: r, graphics

I have those data:

```
require(tidyverse)

(df <- tribble( ~id,    ~group,          ~event,
                 1,        "A",    "2010/01/23",
                 2,        "B",    "2010/02/13",
                 3,        "A",    "2011/03/21",
                 4,        "B",    "2010/01/20",
                 5,        "B",    "2012/11/03",
                 6,        "A",    "2012/08/12"))

(df$event <- as.POSIXct(df$event, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

And I want to trace a graphic with x = time / y = count of events / color = group.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
(
  df
  %>% group_by(group)
  %>% arrange(event)
  %>% mutate(N = row_number())
  %>% ggplot(aes(x=event, y=N, color=group))
   +  geom_line()
)
```

[image]